# remove row names from sf dataframe

Tags: r, r-sf

I have a scenario where I have a list of sf dataframes with rownames. I need to remove these rowname but preserve the geometry column. I am working dynamically with functions so if feasible I would like a way to remove them that doesn't involve converting to a regular dataframe, stripping off the geometry column and then back to sf dataframe. Any ideas? Here is some example data:

```
library(sf)
nc <- st_read(system.file("shape/nc.shp", package = "sf"))
nc2 <- nc

sf_list <- list(nc = nc, nc2 = nc2)
binded <- do.call(rbind, sf_list)
binded
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Set rownames to NULL

You can use this code to remove row names from a `data.frame`:

```
rownames(binded) <- NULL
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: well that was easy

Comment: It's the beauty of R. ;)